# Can electrons reflect light?

Tags: electricity, visible-light, waves, temperature, electrons

Lately, I have been watching **sparks while connecting my electronic devices**  and I can notice that **electricity is kind of blue**, and theoretically **it's blue because it reflects blue wavelengths??** And that **makes it a particle** (like if I said that light is a particle because photons). So **am I correct?**

If electricity doesn't have that color because of that, then why is it blue?? After asking this now I think the following questions:

1. Does electricity have the exact temperature to produce blue light (in terms of the EM spectrum)??
2. If the answer is no, why does electricity have color??

Comment: The visible component in sparks are not electrons but electrical discharges of air. The blue-purple color comes from the the main emission lines in nitrogen and oxygen. You can see the discharge spectra of gases and some other elements here: http://astro.u-strasbg.fr/~koppen/discharge/. Having said that, electrons can reflect light, it's the (quasi) free electron gas in metals that gives them their shiny appearance.

Comment: @CuriousOne: Why do you leave your reply as a comment and not an answer? Just curious, sine it seems to answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

**Can electrons reflect light?**

Yes. Like CuriosuOne said, electrons are *shiny*. I kid ye not, google on [electrons shiny](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=electrons%20shiny&hl=en-GB&gbv=2&oq=&gs_l=). Metals are shiny because they have free electrons. Check out [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/72368/why-are-most-metals-gray-silver) about the colour of metals, where Ali said a metal is are silvery because it *"reflects all wavelengths specularly (more or less)"*. Also see [this article](http://amasci.com/elect/charge1.html) by William Beatty. I read it some years ago, and this bit stuck with me:

*"Here is a way to see charge directly: look at the surface of a wire. Metals look metallic because they contain a "fluid" composed of movable electrons. This electrical "fluid" is an excellent reflector of light waves, and it causes the surfaces of metals to act like mirrors. It's these same electrons which flow during an electric current. The "silvery" stuff of a metal is the charge."*

**Lately, I have been watching sparks while connecting my electronic devices and I can notice that electricity is kind of blue, and theoretically it's blue because it reflects blue wavelengths?? And that makes it a particle (like if I said that light is a particle because photons). So am I correct?**

No, like CuriousOne said, that's down to the air, not the electrons.