# Why do mirrors look "gray"?

Tags: optics, visible-light, reflection, metals

Or any other silver surface? Perfect silver "colour" just seems to be "reflecting gray", so something that absorbs all wavelengths by the same fraction and reflects everything else specularly. When I scratch it, it gets gray.

So a mirrors are gray and specular reflectors and therefore the colour we commonly call silver is, also, simply gray and specular.
Is that correct or am I heading in the wrong direction here?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/72368/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/200932/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Possibly too complex answer here https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/72368/

Answer (score -2):

Standard mirrors used to be made of silver and silver yes has a grey metallic color to it. Platinum can also be used to make a brighter less grey mirror. A Dielectric mirror reflects best almost all viable light and should have no tint of grey.

Comment: This says nothing about *why* mirrors and/or silver is gray.